# Is it necessary to write only stories on Wattpad

Tags: creative-writing, poetry

I searched on the FAQs on WattPadd, it doesn't mention anything about short writings, or poems, so my question is, Can we write short poems, stories on WattPad apart from their promoted way of creative writing or not?

I have created new account, and I myself am new to writing, I want to know this so I can avoid any report or ban before posting it in wrong manner.

Comment: This is a question which should rather be addressed to the Wattpad community than the Writing.SE community. Don't they have some FAQ or meta discussion forum for defining the scope of their site?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about writing but about the rules of another website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question should really be posted on an FAQ forum concerning Wattpad rather than here, however I will be polite and answer your question.

While it does not state in the guidelines of Wattpad what writing forms can be published and what can't be published you can post whatever form of writing you want on Wattpad as long as it is writing and appropriate for all ages.

So yes, this does in fact mean you can post poems and short stories on Wattpad. But I would suggest, for future, ask these questions on a different site to prevent your posts from getting flagged.